# Access image filenames on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an app that will create a list view containing the image filename and a thumbnail of an image (they images will be loaded via lazy loading).

My problem is that from what I've seen, the images should be in /user/data/Media/DCIM but if I try and look at that directory using Directory.Enumerate("/user/data/Media/DCIM") I'm told the directory doesn't exist.

Is there some special way that I can use so I just enumerate the image filenames on the phone?

I'm using Xamarin.iOS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list of images from the device's photo library, you don't access the filesystem directly - instead you use the [AssetsLibrary](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/AssetsLibrary/) API.

The [Shared Resources](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SharedResources) sample includes code to interact with the Assets Library.